# I'm not sure what the error is detecting as a syntax

Tags: python-3.x

```
print("You arrive at an open cavern and see two piles near the back.")
decision = input("Do you want investigate the left pile or the right pile?")
if decision == "left":
    difficulty += 1
if decision == "right":
    difficulty += 3
if difficulty <= 5:
    print("As you approach the pile you notice that its a pack that was dropped by an adventurer.")
    print("The pack has a sword that might come in useful.")
    ATK += 100
if difficulty >= 6:
    print("As you approach the pile you notice that its moving up and down slowly.")
    print("The pile is actually a", (colored("goblin!", "green"), "it jumps at you, ready to fight.")
    decision = input("Dou you strike left or right?")
    if decision == "right":
        print("The goblin jumps straight into your fist, which knocks it into a 
wall.")
        GOLD += 20
    if decision == "left":
        print("The goblin jumps onto you and scratches your face a few times 
before you throw it into a wall.")
        HP -= 150
        GOLD += 10
    print("The goblin is unconcious.")
print("You continue down the hallway.")
```

I'm not sure what happened it says there's a syntax error. If you run the code it should give the error if you need to know the error message in order to provide help.

Comment: Please include the error message you receive

Comment: Possibly typo, missing closing paren `"it jumps at you, ready to fight."))`

Comment: @davedwards it says that on the line below the one about the goblin that there’s an incorrect syntax and points at the n in the word decision

Comment: that's because the line before is missing a closed paren `)`

Comment: Appears not. It still gives the same error

Comment: Will try again when on pc as I’m on mobile now

Comment: Can verify here https://repl.it/@downshift/EagerMellowPublisher

Comment: Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace line

```
print("The pile is actually a", (colored("goblin!", "green"), "it jumps at you, ready to fight.")
```

with

```
print("The pile is actually a", (colored("goblin!", "green")), "it jumps at you, ready to fight.")
```

Comment: Thanks will also try this out